# Spring Async requests and setting value per thread

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on Spring REST application that talks with multiple database based on tenant that logs in.
I want to set the dbname per thread in the application for that I used Spring **requestContext** which internally uses the **threadLocal** storage.

But now the application that we have can do **async** requests also. We are planning to use **DeferredResult** that would be tied with application threads using threadpools. I am trying to figure out the best way to set that value per thread that is spawned based on async request.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this ?

Comment: Nope. we are still not using async.